# How to check for a newly created channel's parentID on discord?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to send a message to a specific channel (`general`) when a new channel is created in a specific category.

So far, I've gotten the bot to only respond when I create the channel in the correct category, and not in other ones. However, the bot then immediately crashes.

This is my code so far:

```js
client.on("channelCreate", function(channel){
    if (client.channels.fetch(channel.parentID == '1037195863317020743')){
        const general = client.channels.cache.get('1038311273651240960');
        general.send("There's a new outline! Let's see what it turns out to be...");
    }
});
```

The message does appear in the correct channel, but the bot then crashes. This is the error log:

```
C:\Users\whydo\OneDrive\Desktop\JS Discord Test\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:659
        throw new DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
              ^

DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
channel_id[NUMBER_TYPE_COERCE]: Value "false" is not snowflake.
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\whydo\OneDrive\Desktop\JS Discord Test\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:659:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users\whydo\OneDrive\Desktop\JS Discord Test\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:458:14)
    at async REST.request (C:\Users\whydo\OneDrive\Desktop\JS Discord Test\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:902:22)
    at async ChannelManager.fetch (C:\Users\whydo\OneDrive\Desktop\JS Discord Test\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ChannelManager.js:123:18) {
  requestBody: { files: undefined, json: undefined },
  rawError: {
    code: 50035,
    errors: {
      channel_id: {
        _errors: [
          {
            code: 'NUMBER_TYPE_COERCE',
            message: 'Value "false" is not snowflake.'
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    message: 'Invalid Form Body'
  },
  code: 50035,
  status: 400,
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/false'
}
```

The only thing I can think of is that it's something wrong with how I'm sending the message, or how I'm checking the `parentID`. Then again, I am new to discord.js and the answer might be plainly obvious in the error log.

Note: This event triggers when a channel is created inside the server, not through JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`channels.fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) accepts an ID, not a statement. By using `channel.parentID == '1037195863317020743'` inside fetch you're calling it with a boolean as it returns either `true` or `false`. Neither of those cases is valid as a boolean can't be a snoflake/ID. That's why you receive the error *"channel_id[NUMBER_TYPE_COERCE]: Value "false" is not snowflake."*

You don't even need to use `fetch` there. `channel` in your [`channelCreate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-channelCreate) is the newly created channel. You can check its [`parentId`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=parentId) (not `parentID`) like this:

```js
client.on('channelCreate', function (channel) {
  if (channel.parentId === '1037195863317020743') {
    const general = client.channels.cache.get('1038311273651240960');
    general.send("There's a new outline! Let's see what it turns out to be...");
  }
});
```

Comment: Wow. We literally went over booleans a few weeks ago in CS. I was a little arrogant because "I already knew how they work." Thank you!